# How do you reverse the order of items in a list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make the code will reverse the order of a list from `'Monday, Tuesday ,Wednesday ,Thursday, Friday' to 'Friday, Thursday, Wednesday, Tuesday, Monday'`. Whenever I run the code all that appears is

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]'

I think the problem may be that I have declared the elements in the list wrong.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> (new string[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"});
        list.Reverse();
        Console.WriteLine(list);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
Console.WriteLine(list);
```

by

```
foreach(string item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

You need to iterate the list. Here you have a complete example of the reverse method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b0axc2h2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, working now :)

Comment: @ShaanKulkarni, if the answer is correct, it's usual to accept it

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler how to convert this list to a string. The default `ToString` functionality for complex types is to output the name of the type.

What you can do is join the list before outputting it:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
```

But it all depends on the exact output you are expecting.